# Reactive's Monad and Applicative instances in Conal Elloit's FRP

Tags: haskell, frp

[Conal Elliott's paper](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/push-pull-frp.pdf) has the following definitions:

```
Future a = (Time, a)
Stepper :: a -> Event a -> Reactive a
Ev :: Future (Reactive a) -> Event a
never : Event a
instance Monad Reactive
```

```
rA :: Reactive String
rA = "IA" `Stepper` (Ev (1, "1A" `Stepper` never))

rB :: Reactive String
rB = "IB" `Stepper` (Ev (1, "1B" `Stepper` never))

rC1 :: Reactive String
rC1 = (++) <$> rA <*> rB
rC1 = "IAIB" `Stepper` (Ev (1, "IA1B" `Stepper` never))
```

I believe the above is correct.

```
rC2 :: Reactive String
rC2 = rA >>= (\a -> (a++) <$> rB)
```

Should `rC1 = rC2`?

Based on the definition in the paper it appears that `"IA1B" and "1AIB"` would be included in between `"IAIB"` and `"1A1B"` in `rC2`.

Doesn't that violate a Monad law `(<*>) = ap`? Shouldn't `rC1 = rC2`? Or I am misunderstanding something.

[Here is the Idris code I am using](https://pastebin.com/3RcS3Hrd)

Comment: Which monad law do you think that violates? The monad laws do not tell us anything about the relationship between `>>=` and `<*>`, only about the structure of the monadic operations (just `>>=` and `return`)

Comment: @trpnd `(<*>) = ap` where `ap m1 m2 = m1 >>= (\x1 -> m2 >>= \x2 -> return (x1 x2))`

Comment: @trpnd, it's actually listed as an Applicative law in the documentation, iirc, but we generally do require conherence between monad and Applicative

Comment: Technically, that's more of a convention than a law. Though in the cases where it's violated, it is expected that there is some sense in which the two things are equivalent, even if not identical. See things like [haxl](https://simonmar.github.io/posts/2015-10-20-Fun-With-Haxl-1.html) for instance, where `(<*>)` can run things in parallel but `ap` can't.

Comment: Could you show the monad instance you are consulting to compute `rC2`?  It looks like maybe you are using `Event`'s monad instead of `Reactive`'s

Comment: @luqui see section 7.1.3 on [the paper](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/push-pull-frp.pdf)

Comment: @luqui I may very well be reading the pseudocode wrong

Comment: It still seems like we should only get 2 values in `rC2`, since the monad chooses the first arriving future and discards the other. How did you compute `rC2`? Could you show your work? (I don't *necessarily* doubt you, I just need to see more detail and am out on my phone not in a position to do the calculation myself.)

Comment: @luqui Idris code I used to compute it. https://pastebin.com/3RcS3Hrd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two bugs in this story. The example given by the question actually only exposes the first one, but while working through it I found another more serious bug in the definition of `join`.

The first bug is minor: it is about handling simultaneous events. Your `race` function allows you to merge simultaneous events. This is taken advantage of in `(<*>)`, but then in your definition of `join`, the `These` case pretends that the left (inner) event happens first. So if you think of implementing `(<*>)` using `join`, and the two behaviors have simultaneous events, `join` will not merge them.

In the case of reactive behaviors, two simultaneous events are undistinguishable from two events that happen very close to each other in time, and in any case, the last one wins, so it should not matter whether the previous one appears in the stream or not. This would break down if you start counting events for example, and from that I would simply conclude that such an operation should not be allowed on behaviors.

I think the `=` symbol that appears in laws is often taken too *syntactically* (if you allow me to call it so), whereas there are various situations, such as this, where it's just more flexible to read it *semantically*. Often they coincide, so it's also hard to really see the point unless you're used to think about it formally.

From that point of view, it would be reasonable to ignore this as "not a bug". It still seems possible to fix the implementation so that the laws do hold syntactically; that would make everyone happy at any rate.

---

To understand the second bug, you must take another look at the meaning of `join :: Reactive (Reactive a) -> Reactive a`.

A `r :: Reactive (Reactive a)` is an evolving behavior. At some time you get behavior `x` (whose inner variations are not shown), then behavior `y`, then behavior `z`... So schematically it looks like a stream of behaviors

```
xxxxx...
yyyyy...
zzzzz...
...
```

If we think of behaviors as functions of time `r :: Time -> (Time -> a)`, `join` samples `r` at time `t`, that's another  behavior `r t :: Time -> a`, which itself gets sampled at time `t`: `(join r) t = r t t`. In other words, you take the diagonal behavior:

```
x
 y
  z
```

Thus, if we look back to the event-driven definition of `Reactive`, it is only natural to forget events as soon as a new behavior appears. And indeed, the definition of `join` as it appears in the paper does that by racing with `join <$> urr`, which forgets about the inner behavior `ur`. However that only accounts for one side of the diagonal:

```
x
yy
zzz
```

Because `Reactive` behaviors are streams of events, inner streams of a `Reactive (Reactive a)` can contain events that occur before the stream's own appearance. Thus, when you get a `Future (Reactive a)`, you also need a way to truncate events from before the `Future` happens:

```
actualize :: Future (Reactive a) -> Future (Reactive a)
-- Exercise for the reader
```

and use that somewhere in `join`.

Comment: Using actualize gave me the desired behavior

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer to show the correct definition of join.